# Adding libraries to portable python

Tags: python, libraries, easy-install, portable-python

So I'm currently using portable python and I need to add the neurolab library. On command line I tried moving to the scripts directory and running

```
easy_install.exe neurolab
```

Then another command line window opens and it's found the neurolab project on google code and its listing files. Then it zips through a ton of lines and the window closes.

However neurolab isn't added to my portable python...

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: there should be a `lib/site-packages` folder in the portable python folder. if you have an other python installed maybe it installes it to there. does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like pure Python library. If that is the case you can install it without easy_install by following these steps:

1. Download from PyPi https://pypi.python.org/pypi/neurolab
2. Unpack the tar.gz file with Winzip, 7-zip or other tool [image]
3. Copy contents of "neurolab" (marked on the picture) folder to App\Lib\site-packages\ in Portable Python
4. Use it !

Comment: I don't know if it's an error in neurolab or a problem in copying into directory but when I ran their example I got an invalid syntax error on:

    except TrainStop as msg:

in the source code for neurolab. If it turns out it's in the library I'll accept this answer :)

Comment: Could you post which example are you trying to run and with what parameters ?

Comment: Just the example on this page: https://code.google.com/p/neurolab/ when the network reaches the desired accuracy or end epochs the exception TrainStop is raised, it's when TrainStop is caught as an exception it fails src code is here https://code.google.com/p/neurolab/source/browse/trunk/neurolab/core.py